# Window in Win32 application won't close normally

Tags: c, winapi

## Original Problem:

I have a window that cannot be closed immediately after being created despite my window procedure function being able to detect the `WM_CLOSE` message, and calling `PostQuitMessage` and letting Windows continue to handle the window messages with `DefWindowProc`.

But, after moving the window by dragging the title bar, it seems to be able to close normally.

The code for the my window procedure function is the following:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK OnEvent(HWND handle, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_QUIT:
        {
            printf("WM_QUIT\n");
            break;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            printf("WM_CLOSE\n");
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(handle, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

So besides sending the `WM_MOVE` message to my window or using `exit(0)` in the `WM_CLOSE` case block, how can I ensure that my window can be closed immediately after being created?

## New Question:

After passing `NULL` to the `hWnd` parameter of `GetMessageW`, instead of my window handle, the window now closes properly hence answering my previous question.

Therefore, why did the `GetMessageW` function previously not retrieve the `WM_QUIT` message with the provided handle of the only window, instead of using `NULL` as the `hWnd` parameter?

Comment: Not tested, calling `PostQuitMessage(0);` and not calling `DefWindowProc` for message `WM_QUIT` may not be good.

Comment: It may useful for you. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381396%28v=vs.85%29.aspx And, after `printf("WM_QUIT\n");`, there're no `break;`. Is it OK?

Comment: `WM_QUIT` will never come through to your WndProc unless something is seriously wrong.

Comment: @gyu-don `DestroyWindow` is already being called after the '`GetMessage` loop' in my main function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A *properly* written message loop will never dispatch a `WM_QUIT` message to a window procedure, it will simply break the loop when `GetMessage()` returns 0 when it receives a `WM_QUIT` message:

[GetMessage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx)

> If the function retrieves a message other than WM_QUIT, the return value is nonzero.
>
> **If the function retrieves the WM_QUIT message, the return value is zero.**
>
> If there is an error, the return value is -1. For example, the function fails if hWnd is an invalid window handle or lpMsg is an invalid pointer. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

In response to `WM_CLOSE`, you should be calling [`DestroyWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx) instead of `PostQuitMessage()` directly (the default behavior of `DefWindowProc(WM_CLOSE)` is to call `DestroyWindow()` for you).  You need a `WM_DESTROY` handler that should then call `PostQuitMessage()`:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK OnEvent(HWND handle, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            printf("WM_CLOSE\n");
            DestroyWindow(handle);
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            printf("WM_DESTROY\n");
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return DefWindowProc(handle, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

This is documented on MSDN:

[Closing the Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381396.aspx)

Here is the flow chart from that page:

[image: flow chart]

As for the `GetMessage()` issue, if you read the documentation for [`GetMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936.aspx) and [`PostQuitMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644945.aspx) more carefully, you will see that the `WM_QUIT` message posted by `PostQuitMessage()` is not a *window* message.  Passing a non-NULL `HWND` to `GetMessage()` only retrieves messages from `PostMessage()` and `SendMessage()` that are intended for that specific `HWND` <sup>1</sup>.  `GetMessage()` will ignore any messages that are not intended for that `HWND`, which includes *thread* messages from `PostThreadMessage()` and `PostQuitMessage()`.  Passing a NULL `HWND` to `GetMessage()` allows it to return any pending message, including `WM_QUIT`.

<sup>1</sup> which is dangerous to do, BTW: [The dangers of filtering window messages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/02/09/369804.aspx)

Comment: well, that was embarrassing although I now understand my errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem when I called `GetMessage()` in my loop with the handle of the main window as the second argument:

```
GetMessage(&msg, hMainWindow, 0, 0)
```

instead of NULL to specify that I want to handle messages for the whole thread / application instance:

```
GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)
```

The WM_CLOSE messages would lead to WM_QUIT messages, but GetMessage() will ignore these when it's only looking for messages for a particular window. From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage#parameters):

> If hWnd is NULL, GetMessage retrieves messages for any window that belongs to the current thread, and any messages on the current thread's message queue whose hwnd value is NULL (see the MSG structure). Therefore if hWnd is NULL, both window messages and thread messages are processed.

What exactly causes moving of the window to have subsequent closing attempts succeed is however still beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that I had found was that when you had set your window classes (WNDCLASSEX) windows procedure (lpfnWndProc) I had set it to the default window procedure and had not used a custom built window procedure. So when you had closed it nothing would occur.